# Modal PopUp not showing correctly on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

The modal pop up does not show correctly on some phones. The window goes too far in the right and cannot be closed as the close button is on the top right. I moved the X button in the middle but still the modal is far right. On some iPhones, like the 11,12  however it shows perfectly. All the code is below. Any help will be highly appreciated.  Thank you!

[Wrongfully shown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcrc3.png)

```
      
<style>
    .modal-dialog {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}

.modal-box{ font-family: 'Quantico', sans-serif; }
.modal-box .show-modal{
background: linear-gradient(#444,#222);
color: #fff;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 400;
text-transform: capitalize;
letter-spacing: 1px;
padding: 12px 20px;
margin: 80px auto 0;
border: none;
outline: none;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
display: block;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.modal-box .show-modal:hover,
.modal-box .show-modal:focus{
color: #fff;
outline: none;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.modal-backdrop.in{ opacity: 0; }
.modal-box .modal-dialog{
width: 450px;
margin: 70px auto 0;
}
.modal.fade .modal-dialog{ transform: translateY(-100px); }
.modal.in .modal-dialog{ transform: translate(0); }
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content{
text-align: center;
border: none;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);  
}  
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content:before{
content: "";
background: linear-gradient(to right,#FFA678,#FF1B1A);
border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
display: block;
clear: both;
}
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .close{
color: #000;
font-size: 50px;
font-weight: 300;
text-align: center;
line-height: 25px;
width: 50px;
height: 35px;
padding-left: 1px;
border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
overflow: hidden;
opacity: 1;
position: absolute;
left: auto;
top: 27px;
right: 0px;
z-index: 1;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .close:hover{ color: #555; }
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .close span{
margin: -6px 0 0;
display: block;
}
div.image::before {
content:url(http://motopara.com/images/EVO_17_Popup.jpg);

}
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body .title{
color: #000;
font-size: 37px;
font-weight: 500;
letter-spacing: 1px;
display: block;
text-transform: capitalize;
margin: 0 0 20px;
}
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body .title::after{
content: "";
background: linear-gradient(to right,#FFA678,#FF0000);
width: 100px;
height: 6px;
margin: 20px auto 0;
border-radius: 10px;
display: block;
clear: both;
}
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body .description{
color: #7c0303;
font-size: 20px;
margin: 0 0 30px;
}
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body .btn{
color: #FF1B1A;
background: linear-gradient(#444,#222);
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 600;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1px;
padding: 12px 40px;
margin: 0 auto -57px;
border: none;
border-radius: 5px;
display: block;
transition: all 0.6s;
}
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body .btn:hover{
color:#fff;
text-shadow: 0 0 5px #FF1B1A;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #FF1B1A;
}
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body .btn:focus{ outline: none; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
.modal-dialog{ width: 85% !important; }
}

</style>
```

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="modal-box">
            <!-- Modal --> 
              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        </button><br>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="image"></div>
                            <h2 class="title">BLACK FRIDAY DEALS</h2>
                            <p class="description">Get your Rebel paramotor on SPECIAL prices NOW!<br><br>Contact us for more information.</p>
                            <p style="background-color:black;">offers are valid until stock lasts</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's hard to say because you haven't provided a minimal reproducible example of your problem. `.modal-dialog{ max-width: 100%!important; }`?

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .modal-dialog {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}

.modal-box{ font-family: 'Quantico', sans-serif; }
.modal-box .show-modal{
background: linear-gradient(#444,#222);
color: #fff;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 400;
text-transform: capitalize;
letter-spacing: 1px;
padding: 12px 20px;
margin: 80px auto 0;
border: none;
outline: none;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
display: block;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.modal-box .show-modal:hover,
.modal-box .show-modal:focus{
color: #fff;
outline: none;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.modal-backdrop.in{ opacity: 0; }
.modal-box .modal-dialog{
width: 450px;
margin: 70px auto 0;
}
.modal.fade .modal-dialog{ transform: translateY(-100px); }
.modal.in .modal-dialog{ transform: translate(0); }
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content{
text-align: center;
border: none;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);  
}  
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content:before{
content: "";
background: linear-gradient(to right,#FFA678,#FF1B1A);
border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
display: block;
clear: both;
}
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .close{
color: #000;
font-size: 50px;
font-weight: 300;
text-align: center;
line-height: 25px;
width: 50px;
height: 35px;
padding-left: 1px;
border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
overflow: hidden;
opacity: 1;
position: absolute;
left: auto;
top: 27px;
right: 0px;
z-index: 1;
transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .close:hover{ color: #555; }
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .close span{
margin: -6px 0 0;
display: block;
}
div.image::before {
content:url(http://motopara.com/images/EVO_17_Popup.jpg);
}
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body .title{
color: #000;
font-size: 37px;
font-weight: 500;
letter-spacing: 1px;
display: block;
text-transform: capitalize;
margin: 0 0 20px;
}
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body .title::after{
content: "";
background: linear-gradient(to right,#FFA678,#FF0000);
width: 100px;
height: 6px;
margin: 20px auto 0;
border-radius: 10px;
display: block;
clear: both;
}
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body .description{
color: #7c0303;
font-size: 20px;
margin: 0 0 30px;
}
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body .btn{
color: #FF1B1A;
background: linear-gradient(#444,#222);
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 600;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1px;
padding: 12px 40px;
margin: 0 auto -57px;
border: none;
border-radius: 5px;
display: block;
transition: all 0.6s;
}
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body .btn:hover{
color:#fff;
text-shadow: 0 0 5px #FF1B1A;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #FF1B1A;
}
.modal-box .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-body .btn:focus{ outline: none; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
.modal-dialog{ width: 85% !important; }


.modal.fade .modal-content {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 30px);
    overflow: auto;
}
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    margin-top: 0;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="modal-box">
                        <!-- Modal --> 
                          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                                    </button><br>
            
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="image"></div>
                                        <h2 class="title">BLACK FRIDAY DEALS</h2>
                                        <p class="description">Get your Rebel paramotor on SPECIAL prices NOW!<br><br>Contact us for more information.</p>
                                        <p style="background-color:black;">offers are valid until stock lasts</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```